# OWL-API 4.0.1 compatiable pellet reasoner?

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl-api, pellet

I was using OWL-API version 4.0.1 together with Pellet reasoner version 2.3.6 as can be seen in the extracted from pom file maven dependency section below

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-apibinding</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
        <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6-ansell</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i complied  the project, i found an error as below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError  at
>   org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.loadFactories(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:99)
>     at
>   org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.configure(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:52)
>     at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:230)
>     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)    at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)     at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)     at
>   org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.(OWLManager.java:43)
>     at
>   sematicdm.parser.CreateIndividualsClass.main(CreateIndividualsClass.java:73)

In the class createIndividualsClass the line which raises the error is below:

```
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
```

Is it a compatibility issues ? If so, what version of pellet resoner should i include in the pom file?

Comment: It seems it is a compatibility issue, since Pellet hasn't update from owl-api v3. I don't think you can find a Pellet for version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a Pellet version compatible with OWLAPI 4 yet - I'm planning to release one at the end of this week. Keep an eye on https://github.com/ignazio1977/pellet for updates.

Currently, the latest versions of FaCT++ (1.6.3) and JFact (4.0.0) are compatible with OWLAPI 4.0.1. I am not aware of the current status for other reasoners - HermiT is planning an update but has not completed that yet.

Comment: You rock! Just when I need it :)

Comment: I receive the same exception like above when I try to add pellet to owl api 4. Any hints which versions are compatible? I can't find a proper maven setup that works.

Comment: pellet 2.4.0-ignazio1977 http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7C2.4.0-ignazio

Answer (score 0):

Pallet is now supporting up to OWLAPI 4.0.2 and Protege 5.0 (As Plugin) beta 21 and newer.

https://github.com/ignazio1977/pellet/commit/5ee814edd52df9aa9366db1fae76f7e9ea9057aa